# Redirect to link using Angular UI Directive Typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead directive for a project and I want to redirect to a dynamic URL based on what is selected in the typeahead. I'm trying to use the typeahead as a search box.

I've looked at the documentation (trying to RTFM), so I know there is a `typeaheadOnSelect` attribute that I can use, but I'm not sure how to tie this to a link. I'm using a JSON file of objects and each object has a specific ID. I was hoping to be able to link directly in the typeahead attribute like so:

```
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="selectedPerson" typeahead="person as person.name for person in person | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-min-length="3" typeaheadOnSelect="#/100_Ages/{{person.id}}" ng-init="" />
    </div>
```

But that didn't work. I think I need a specific controller for this, but I'm not sure. The typeahead directive seems to work so well, so I imagine there's an easy solution, but I can't find it.

Right now, my controller for this Typeahead looks like this:

```
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.person = data;
      });
}
```

[This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A3oWoWTnNuonAqwWGaDD?p=preview) shows everything in action. My router for this project is setup using a dynamic URL based on the each JSON id, like so:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/app/:personId', {templateUrl: 'partials/person.html', controller: DetailCtrl}).
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can watch for a change to the selectedPerson model. Here is an example:

```
function TypeaheadCtrl ($scope, $http, $location, $log, $timeout) {
  $http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.person = data;
  });
  $scope.$watch('selectedPerson', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue){
      $log.info('/100_Ages/' + $scope.selectedPerson.id);
      $location.path('/100_Ages/' + $scope.selectedPerson.id);
    }
  });
}
```

**Updated:** After updating to v0.4.0, I was able to do this:

```
function TypeaheadCtrl ($scope, $http, $location, $log, $timeout) {
  $http.get('person.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.people = data;
  });
  $scope.onSelect = function($item, $model, $label){
    $scope.$item = $item;
    $scope.$model = $model;
    $scope.$label = $label;
    $log.info($scope.$item);
    $log.info($scope.$model);
    $log.info($scope.$label);
    $location.path('/person/' + $scope.$item.id);
  }
}
```

and then in the HTML, I did this:

```
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for a name or age" ng-model="selectedPerson" typeahead="person.id as person.name for person in people | filter:$viewValue" typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-min-length="3" ng-init="" />
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is almost there, but it is trying to select someone before the typeahead can even present the list of dropdown options. Ideally, I'd like it to show all the options possible for that search, then they pick one, then it redirects. Is that possible?

Comment: This is much closer. The link is redirecting, but it is directing itself to the projects home page (which has the link 100_Ages/0 as a route possibility to cover someone swiping backwards on the first person page). [Here is a hosted version of the site](http://bengal.missouri.edu/~wjg2q2/100_ages/app/#/100_Ages/1), so you can see what I mean. 

Hit the magnifying glass to bring up the search. If you inspect it when someone's name is highlighted, you'll see a tab index of '-1' on the link. I think that's the source of the problem, but I'm not sure why it'd be happening. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: See my comment, the tab index is logging a '-1' instead of each person's id. Trying to see if it is something on my end, too.

Comment: Ah, figured it out. The route on the $location.path was incorrect, but that's because I used a more generalized route for my Plunkr example. Thank you much for the help, would've never figured that out otherwise.

Comment: The updated method is perfect. Should be added to the documentation!